# How to use Xml Pull Parsing to access all the values from the given images and set them to text views?

Tags: java, android

I need to use Xml Pull Parsing to access all values from start tags to set these values to the text views. There are multiple START TAGS in this XML file and I am unable to use use this XML file for required output.

Whenever I call Tbl START TAG for Tax then it will get all the values from all Tax from other START TAGS.

```html
<NewDataSet>
<Tbl>
<FromBillNo>536332</FromBillNo>
<ToBillNo>536851</ToBillNo>
<Total_Sale>202684.54</Total_Sale>
<Tax>21978.8600</Tax>
<Net_x0020_Sale>173628.7000</Net_x0020_Sale>
<Service_Charge_Amount>10418.2400</Service_Charge_Amount>
<Discount>18637.60</Discount>
<Round_Off>-2.80</Round_Off>
<STax>0.00</STax>
<Sur_Ch>0.00</Sur_Ch>
<Ser_Ch>0.00</Ser_Ch>
<NoofTran>520</NoofTran>
<TotalAPC>396.20</TotalAPC>
</Tbl>
<Tbl1>
<TotalAmt>202681.74</TotalAmt>
<Cash>206023.00</Cash>
<Credit_x0020_Card>0.00</Credit_x0020_Card>
<Coupons>0.00</Coupons>
<Time>11:41PM</Time>
<Cheque>0.00</Cheque>
<FOC>18556.80</FOC>
<resturant>24762.00</resturant>
<tkAwy>141182.00</tkAwy>
<HD>40079.00</HD>
<DineIn>0.00</DineIn>
<sendback>0.00</sendback>
</Tbl1>
<Tbl2>
<Amount>117841.0000</Amount>
<Cashier>ABBAS</Cashier>
</Tbl2>
<Tbl2>
<Amount>29067.0000</Amount>
<Cashier>SARIQ</Cashier>
</Tbl2>
<Tbl2>
<Amount>11012.0000</Amount>
<Cashier>AZEEM</Cashier>
</Tbl2>
<Tbl2>
<Amount>48103.0000</Amount>
<Cashier>NAGI</Cashier>
</Tbl2>
<Tbl3>
<FromBillNo>536332</FromBillNo>
<ToBillNo>536851</ToBillNo>
<Company_Name>Ganesh Nagar Outlet</Company_Name>
<Company_Name1>1</Company_Name1>
<NetSale>173628.70</NetSale>
<bill_amount>206023.00</bill_amount>
</Tbl3>
<Table1>
<Amount>540.0000</Amount>
<Tax>5.0000</Tax>
</Table1>
<Table1>
<Amount>186640.4000</Amount>
<Tax>12.5000</Tax>
</Table1>
<Table1>
<Amount>5094.0000</Amount>
<Tax>20.0000</Tax>
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are considerably more likely to get high quality answers if you include the XML in your question as text. Other users cannot copy and paste your image to test their solutions.

Comment: I hope now it will be more understandable and easy to read my problem. So please provide me a solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Everyone here is a volunteer. They also don't tend to respond well to statements that your problem is "urgent" or required "as soon as possible". Personally, your question falls outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Sorry Sir, if possible then provide me a solution.

Comment: No need to apologise, it's all a learning experience. But I don't personally know the answer to your question.